# I'm having issues with making a scoreboard with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm trying to develop a discord bot with discord.js, and I wanted to make a scoreboard, but for some reason I can't make the variable change when a command to add a point to the scoreboard is called. Can somebody help? The points constantly stay at 0. Also I'm kind of a beginner at programming so if you could explain in an easy way to understand, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
    if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === 'r!score x 1') {
        x = x + 1;
        msg.channel.send("Team y has won a point, now they're at " + x + "!")
    }else if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === 'r!score y 1') {
        y = y + 1;
        msg.channel.send("Team y has won a point, now they're at " + y + "!")
    } else if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === 'r!placar') {
        
        const scoreboard = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor("#0099ff")
    .setTitle("**Scoreboard**")
    .addFields(
        {name: "__Team X__", value: x + " points"},
        {name: "__Team Y__", value: y + " points"}
    );
        msg.channel.send(scoreboard)
        
    } 
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to use Message Collectors, but I will show a different way. This can be adapted to your code to fit some sort of game.

```js
let x = 0, 
y = 0;
client.on("message", msg => {
  if(msg.content === 'r!score x 1') {
    msg.channel.send(`Team x has won a point, now they're at ${++x}!`)
  } else if(msg.content === 'r!score x 2') {
    msg.channel.send(`Team y has won a point, now they're at ${++y}!`)
  } else if(msg.content === 'r!placar') {
    const scoreboard = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setColor("#0099ff")
    .setTitle("**Scoreboard**")
    .addFields(
      {name: "__Team X__", value: x + " points"},
      {name: "__Team Y__", value: y + " points"}
    );
        msg.channel.send(scoreboard)
  }
})
```

## Why is your code not working?

Your code is only saying 0 for both because you are declaring the variable inside the function. Every callback, the variable gets declared and the value is set as 0. You then check if the message content is `r!placar` then send the embed where `x` is `0` and `y` is the same. I declared it outside of the callback which lets you access it from anywhere in the callback, keeping the value.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as correct if it helped!